# Binary treatment based on a continuous variable (Stata)

Tags: data-visualization, stata

I want to create a scatter plot showing my treatment assignment on the y-axis and the margin of winning on the x-axis.

To create a binary treatment variable, where a margin over 0 indicates that a Republican candidate won the local election.

```
gen republican_win = (margin>0)
```

Here is a data example:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input double margin float republican_win
  -.356066316366196 0
   -.54347825050354 0
  -.204092293977737 0
  -.449720650911331 1
  -.201149433851242 1
  -.505899667739868 0
  -.206885248422623 1
end
```

To generate a scatter plot, I ran this. While the code ran well, I was wondering if it would be possible to display a continuous distribution of the margin of Republican wins and losses?

```
scatter margin republican_win
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean plotting the logisitic distribution ? Maybe this can help: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/webbooks/logistic/chapter1/logistic-regression-with-statachapter-1-introduction-to-logistic-regression-with-stata/

Comment: "display a continuous distribution" is too vague a question. Histogram, density curve, dot plot, quantile plot, box plot???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the predicted probabilities by storing them in a variable, and then plot it at the same time as your scatter plot.
I would then reverse the axes to show your logistic distribution.

```
logit republican_win margin
predict win_hat

twoway scatter win_hat republican_win margin, ///
connect(l i) msymbol(i 0) sort ylabel(0 1)
```

There are not enough data points in your data example to show a nice fitted curve, but I'm sure it will look better on your whole dataset.